# Reducing output of GraphQL

Tags: graphql, graphql-compose-mongoose

I have set up a GraphQL-mongoose-express-apollo combo as per this [guide](https://getstream.io/blog/tutorial-create-a-graphql-api-with-node-mongoose-and-express/).

When I run a query to get multiple results, is there a way to reduce the resulting array before I actually get to processing the response from the query.

Query:

```
query GetSomeUsers {
  userMany (limit: 3){
    _id
  }
}
```

Actual output:

```
{
  "data": {
    "userMany": [
      {
        "_id": "5e950543cb48dbaafc60722d"
      },
      {
        "_id": "5e950543cb48dbaafc60722e"
      },
      {
        "_id": "5e950547cb48dbaafc60722f"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Desired output:

```
{
  "data": {
    "userMany": [
        "5e950543cb48dbaafc60722d",
        "5e950543cb48dbaafc60722e",
        "5e950547cb48dbaafc60722f"
    ]
  }
}
```

So far I have only found something that seems to be relevant in an article on [GraphQL Leveler](https://www.fourkitchens.com/blog/development/graphql-leveler-controlling-shape-query/), but I don't see how it would work with graphql-compose-mongoose, as the GraphQL schema is automatically generated and there does not seem to be any place in the code to put in that LevelerObjectType in place of a GraphQLObjectType.